# Constructor can read height, but not width?

Tags: class, object, constructor, processing

Beginner, so apologies if terminology is off or if I'm maybe not as descript as I need to be (or too descript). ****Edit: I was trying not to post all my code, but it looks like that's necessary, so I've updated this post.*

I'm creating a sketch in Processing with very basic floating bubbles. To do this, I've made a class named Bubble in a second tab:

```
class Bubble {

  int x;
  int y;
  int d;
  int s;
  color c;

  Bubble(){
    
    d = int(random(10, 100));
    x = int(random(d/2, width-d/2));
    y = height - d/2;
    s = int(random(-10, -1));
    c = color(random(255), random(255), random(255));
  }

  void render(){
    fill(c);
    circle(x, y, d);
  }
  
  void move(){
    y += s;
  }
  
  void reset(){
    if (y+d/2 <= 0){
      y = height-d/2;
    }
  }
}
```

Now, back on the first tab, I have this:

```
Bubble b1 = new Bubble();
Bubble b2 = new Bubble();
Bubble b3 = new Bubble();

void setup(){
  size(1200,800);
}

void draw(){
  background(0);
  
  b1.render();
  b1.move();
  b1.reset();
  println(b1.x);
  
  b2.render();
  b2.move();
  b2.reset();
  println(b2.x);
  
  b3.render();
  b3.move();
  b3.reset();
  println(b3.x);
}
```

When I run this, the y position resets just as intended. But for SOME reason, the circles refuse to spawn past 80-something on the x axis. I assume that means it's defaulting to 100 pixels for width...but why? Why can it access the height I've assigned, but not the width?

Comment: Oh, sorry, could've sworn I did - fixed now. And to answer, it's Java. I'm using Processing to write all this, though, and I'm told that's kinda a watered-down Java - not sure if that's true but I figured I'd include that tidbit just in case.

Comment: You need to provide more code. With what you provide I do not see where you declare and initialize height and width. If I had to guess this is an issue with scope. Or you need to add the height and width as parameters to your bubble constructor.

Comment: *"I'm told that's kinda a watered-down Java."* - But its not Java.  (Hint:  [shandy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shandy) is a kind of watered-down beer, but it isn't beer.)

Comment: This code does not compile in Java, a function with name `int` is not even possible in Java. As I understand, you are facing real problem. Why do you post pseudo code? Especially when you suspect the programming language to be the reason?

Comment: Processing is a java-based language, but it is _not pure java and probably shouldn't have that tag.

Comment: @CoronA , it's Processing. Not pure Java. So *int* is absolutelly legal and possible.

Comment: Maybe it would help to link the [Processing Home Page](https://processing.org/). The first time I read "Processing", I suspected a translation error from a non-native-speaker.

Comment: Thanks all - I've added the rest of the code, removed the Java tag, and clarified this is all in Processing. I just saw that the 'mode' at the top right was set to Java, so I assumed that's what language it was. Hopefully now it's more clear.

Comment: The Processing editor is using Java under the hood, but have made it easy for users so we don't have to directly use it (although the editor will run pure Java if you really want to use it).

Answer (score 2):

OK, the real reason why your example doesn't work is because the environment starts the sketch with sizes 100,100, and You **later in the void setup** changes to 800,600.
Analyze that:

```java
Out o1 = new Out("size before setup");

void setup () {
  size(512, 256);

  Out o2 = new Out("size after setup");
}

class Out {
  Out(String str) {
    println(str + ": " + width, height);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
size before setup: 100 100
size after setup: 512 256
```

Offcourse You can init, and construct, global objects before setup(), but in that case Your width and height will be = 100.

Comment: Good point.  Of course we had no way of knowing that was the problem until all the code was posted.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, finally! The problem was literally the first three lines of the first tab, trying to both declare and initialize b1, b2, and b3 at once. Instead, I needed to declare in the global scope and then initialize inside of setup(). Kinda made me feel stupid, but, oh well. Anyway, here it is:

```
Bubble b1;
Bubble b2;
Bubble b3;

void setup(){
  size(1200,800);
  
  b1 = new Bubble();
  b2 = new Bubble();
  b3 = new Bubble();
}
```

Now the bubbles spawn along the entirety of the screen. :)

That said, it still makes me wonder how my class was able to access height and not width. But, this fixed it, so I'll take it lol.

Comment: Posting all the code is a big help. Setup() only runs once so the parameters of the bubbles doesn't change once established, except for y.  I think it would be more interesting if you had an array of about a hundred balloons being fired all across the x axis.

Comment: Definitely not the interesting answer, but correct - I didn't need the colors and x value to be able to change after reset in the same run. But that said, now I'm curious to see if I CAN make it do that, so I might give it a shot. I could use the practice lol. Thanks for the help! (:

Comment: It's fairly easy to do if you set up an array; you can then set the size of the array (number of bubbles) to be whatever you want it to be.